# Running parallel queries in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

How does spark handle concurrent queries? I have read a bit about spark and underlying RDD's but I am unable to understand how concurrent queries would be handled?

For example if I run a query which loads the data in memory and the entire available memory is consumed and at the same time someone else runs a query involving another set of data, how would spark allocate the memory to both the queries? Also what would be the impact if the priorities are taken into account.

Also can running lots of parallel queries would result in the machines hanging ?

Comment: Do you run two concurrent queries from two different spark drivers?

Comment: Are you talking about two concurrent actions on the same RDD in the same SparkContext?

Comment: It can be on the same RDD or multiple RDD's at the same time. My idea here was that if multiple users are running their jobs on spark, how would memory allocation happen?

Comment: @SeanOwen How can we execute two actions concurrently in spark using Java API. Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly Spark doesn't take the in-memory (RAM) more than threshold limit.

Spark tries to allocate the default in-memory to every job.

If there is insufficient memory for a new job then it tries to spill the in-memory content of LeastRecentlyUsed (LRU) RDD to disk and then allocates to new job.

Optionally you can also specify the storage of RDD like IN-MEMORY only, DISK only, MEMORY AND DISK etc..

Scenario: consider a low in-memory machine with huge no of jobs, then most of the RDDs will be placed in disk only, as per the above approach.
So, the jobs will continue to run but it will not take the advantage of Spark in-memory processing.

Spark does the memory allocation very intelligently.

If Spark used on top-of YARN then Resource manager also takes place in the resource allocation.